# How to create conditional group-by with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = [['A', 'HIGH', 120, 200],
        ['A', 'MID', 350, 200],
        ['B', 'HIGH', 130, 100],
        ['B', 'HIGH', 70, 100],
        ['A', 'MID', 130, 200]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Category', 'Range', 'Total', 'Avg'])
```

Now, I want to create a Group By that when the category is A, it groups by category and Range, while when it is B, it group only by category.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some expected results?

Comment: Given you only have **one** range for B if you group by category and range this will do what you want. If not, can you update the example with one more range for B and provide the expected output?

Comment: I think either you are overthinking or you want to do everything in one line of code `groupby`. You can simply use `.loc` to separate dataframe into smaller ones, then apply `groupby`, and `concat`. This should be more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code. It will also work **B** has multiple **range**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = [['A', 'HIGH', 120, 200],
        ['A', 'MID', 350, 200],
        ['A', 'MID', 130, 200],
        ['B', 'HIGH', 130, 100],
        ['B', 'MID', 70, 100],
        ['B', 'MID', 70, 100]
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Category', 'Range', 'Total', 'Avg'])

df[['Total_New','Avg_New']] = df.assign(group_col = np.where(df['Category']=='A',df.Category+df.Range, df.Category)).\
groupby('group_col')['Total','Avg'].transform('sum')

df
```

Output:

[image]